# WebService REST con JSON de salida

Tags: genexus

Estoy trabajando con genexus evo 3 con generador JavaScript. Tengo un procedimiento de tipo web service un parametro de entrada y salida de tipo SDT:

```
parm(in:&entradaSdt,out:&salidaSdt);
```

Necesito que el procedimiento genere el sgte formato JSON:

```
{"status":"success","messages":[]}
```

Pero el procedimiento me arroja con el sgte formato, lleva el nombre de la varible de salida `&salidaSdt` en el body:

```
{
"salidaSdt": "{"status":"success","messages":[]}"
}
```

¿Cómo puedo generar la respuesta sin el nombre de la variable `salidaSdt` en el body?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado:

Los parámetros de procedimiento quedaron así:

```
parm(in:&entradaSdt,out:&message,out:&status);

&entradaSdt = tipo de dato SDT
&message    = tipo de dato SDT
&status     = tipo de dato varchar
```

Espero que les sirva, saludos.

Comment: genial, no olvides pasar al dia siguiente y marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, por cierto te invito a hacer el [tour]